# Incorrect answer zero where correct answer is very large (precision issue)

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, numerical-value

Define a function `F` as follows:

```
F[α_, x_] = 
  N[Exp[x/2] Abs[Gamma[α/2 + I x /(2 Pi)]]^2, 10];
```

It is a product of two terms. As $x\to\infty$, the first term exponentially increases while the second term exponentially decreases. Their product moderately increases by a power-law.

If I evaluate `F[6, 10000]`, the answer is `6.4163*10^16`, which seems reasonable. However, if I evaluate `F[6, 10000.1]`, the answer is `0.` This is not expected since `F` is a continuous function.

I think the issue is on the precision, so I modified the definition `F` by removing `N`.

```
F[α_, x_] = 
  Exp[x/2] Abs[Gamma[α/2 + I x /(2 Pi)]]^2;
```

Then, even `Gfintemp[6, 10000] // N` gives the wrong answer `0.`.

How can I fix the problem, so that `F` gives a reasonable output for moderate values of $x$, written in exact number or numeric?

Comment: Try higher precision input than machine precision: ``F[6, 10000.1`20]``

Comment: Set the precision inside `F[]` if you want to handle machine-precision inpuit. For instance, `F[\[Alpha]_, x_] := 
  With[{\[Alpha]0 = SetPrecision[\[Alpha], Infinity], 
    x0 = SetPrecision[x, Infinity]},
   N[Exp[x0/2] Abs[Gamma[\[Alpha]0/2 + I x0/(2 Pi)]]^2, 10]
   ];` -- Insteaed of `SetPrecision` could also use `Rationalize` which tends to change the value of the input slightly but also produce smaller denominators.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for your comment. However, your suggested code on `F` does not work; `F[6, 10000.1]` gives unwanted `0.`

Comment: Works for me (see answer). Perhaps you did not copy the full code? Note that `:=` in mine vs. `=` in `F[]` above is significant.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I made a mistake when copy-pasting your code. Now it works for me! Thanks so much for your comments and answer, as always!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try higher precision input than machine precision. Set the precision inside the function if you want to handle machine-precision input.  You can use `SetPrecision[]` or `Rationalize[]`. `Rationalize[]` tends to change the value of the input slightly but also produce smaller denominators.

```
f[\[Alpha]_, x_] := 
  With[{\[Alpha]0 = SetPrecision[\[Alpha], Infinity], 
    x0 = SetPrecision[x, Infinity]},
   N[Exp[x0/2] Abs[Gamma[\[Alpha]0/2 + I x0/(2 Pi)]]^2, 10]
   ];

f2[\[Alpha]_, x_] := 
  With[{\[Alpha]0 = Rationalize[Rationalize@\[Alpha], 0], 
    x0 = Rationalize[Rationalize@x, 0]},
   N[Exp[x0/2] Abs[Gamma[\[Alpha]0/2 + I x0/(2 Pi)]]^2, 10]
   ];
```

Evaluation is nonzero:

```
f[6, 10000.1]

(*  6.416572393*10^16  *)
```

Relative error between the methods on this expression is negligible at 10-digit precision:

```
(f2[6, 10000.1] - f[6, 10000.1])/f[6, 10000.1]

(*  0.*10^-10  *)
```

The difference in the input:

```
With[{x = 10000.1}, 
 N[Rationalize[Rationalize@x, 0] - SetPrecision[x, Infinity], 10]]

(*  -3.637978807*10^-13  *)
```